# PHP Block INSERT Null or 0 into database

Tags: php, mysql, database, isnullorempty

```
//--------Insert Record--------
if(isset($_POST['addbutton']) && $_POST['addbutton']=='create'){
  $invoice_no=$_POST['invoice_no'];
  //Alert field is empty
  if ($invoice_no == "") {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo ' alert("Invoice number field is empty!")';
    echo '</script>';
    header("refresh:1; url=myadmin.php");
  }
```

I have used alert block with empty value, but still record value `0` into my database.

Is there any specific code to block the `0` record into my database?

Comment: None of the code you posted inserts into the database. How are we supposed to tell how to stop that from happening? I suspect you just need to add `exit` after the `header()` call.

Comment: Please read a basic form-handling tutorial. You are missing the basics.